# Changing a keyboard shortcut in Thunderbird

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

In Thunderbird I'd like the CTRL+R shortcut to do a REPLY TO ALL instead of just a REPLY. Is there a way to configure this that does not involve installing third-party extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) allows you to configure keyboard shortcuts.

Read more about it [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension).

Otherwise,You can unzip Thunderbird's chrome .jar files and edit the .dtd files within them, which usually contain the key bindings, if you want something that's not extension-dependent. Here's an example from a DTD file for my extension:

```
<!ENTITY removedupes.remove_duplicates_menuitems.remove.accesskey "D">
<!ENTITY removedupes.remove_duplicates_menuitems.set_originals.accesskey "o">
<!ENTITY key-removedupes.modifiers "alt,shift">
```

this is of course much less convenient than using KeyConfig, but that's the low-level non-dynamic way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I feel one can never be sure about extensions so I will be fiddling with this stuff.

Comment: Where are these files located?

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyconfig` extension:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994

It pretty much does all you can imagine, albeit with some shortcomings.

Answer (score 1):

If `keyconfig` is deprecated for your version of Thunderbird, there is now tbkeys: https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys.